# Handling fragment hash in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am populating a div element called content based on a click event in a text menu.   This is working fine but I would like to handle these scenarios:

1. Refreshing page with # fragment in URL.  Currently, it results in a blank div.
2. Going to the page without # fragment in URL should show populate the div with blog.php

Thanks in advance

Code

```
<!-- Transparent box -->
<div id="box">

<!-- Menu -->
<a href="#blog" onclick="$('#content').load('blog.php')">blog</a> |
<a href="#code" onclick="$('#content').load('code.php')">code</a> |
<a href="#portfolio" onclick="$('#content').load('portfolio.php')">portfolio</a> |
<a href="#about" onclick="$('#content').load('about.php')">about</a>

<div class="bar"></div>

<!-- Content -->
<div id="content"></div>

<div class="bar" id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve by several ways.. Maybe like that:

```
// Run on document ready
$(function() {
    // Get hash or set "#blog" as default
    var hash = document.location.hash || "#blog";

    // Trigger click event of anchor that has href as url hash
    $('[href="'+hash+'"]').click();
});
```